# Iterate through a JSON Tree to retrieve Parent and Child Recursively

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, iteration

I have a JSON file from which I'm retrieving all the keys. I need to retrieve the keys in a parent-child fashion. For eg:

> Parent
>    ----     Child1
>    ----    Child2
>    ----    Child3
>        --------    Child31
>        --------    Child32
>    ----    Child4

Can this be achieved through recursion? For iterating through the file I'm using the following code:

```
function runRecurse(objLevel) {
   for (var innerKey in objLevel) {
      if (objLevel[innerKey] !== null){
         console.log(innerKey);
         runRecurse(objLevel[innerKey]);    
      }
   }                     
}
```

Is there a way to get a result like in the particular format:

NoParent - Parent
Parent - Child1
Parent - Child2
Parent - Child3
Child3 - Child31
Child3 - Child32
Parent - Child4

Comment: please add: data, variables, test run, result, error.

Comment: When I run the code, I'm able to capture the keys but could not identify its parent node.

Comment: please add the missing parts.

Comment: This is the code I'm using.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Removed inneKey5. The code iterates through a sample JSON file and retrieves all the keys. But what I would like to have is to save the parent value and display it along with the child key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184306/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-vin).

Answer (score 2):

For getting all keys as single pathes, you could take an object's entries and iterate by checking if the values are objects as well, then take the sub keys or just only the actual key for the result.

```js
function getKeys(object) {
    return Object
        .entries(object)
        .reduce((r, [k, v]) =>
            r.concat(v && typeof v === 'object'
                ? getKeys(v).map(sub => [k].concat(sub))
                : k
            ),
            []
        );
}

var data = { v1: { Cr: { getrt: { input: { R: { Cd: "nt", Ud: "ing", Pd: "g", Mr: "ng", Se: "ng", Pe: "ing", Psion: "g", Rt: "L", Cd2: "xsring", Cag: "xsngth", NnfigID: "xsng", CryFlag1: "xength", C2: "xength", Custo3: "xength", Cus4: "xngth", tars: "ns", taace: "h.0" }, Reqails: { Amber: "xsd:string", B: "x", KenMI: "xg", targas: "ns", targace: "h" }, Inqutails: { "Inqnt[]": { Ar: "x", B: "x", KI: "x", ts: "ns", tce: "h0" }, tas: "ns", tace: "h" }, Reqdy: { Ise: "Inq", Tnt: "x", Ald: "x", Fme: "x", Fmjke: "xtern", Mme: "xttern", Lame: "xs", Fals: { "Ado[]": { Addme: "x", Adde: "AdnalNam", taas: "", taace: "ht" }, Noents: "x", talias: "n", tapace: "h" }, Ad1: "xh", A2: "x", Ae1: "xs", St: "x", L1: "xs", L2: "xs", Cy: "x", Ste: "S", Pal: "x", Is: { "I[]": { Aine: "x", Set: "xth", L1: "x", L2: "x", C: "x", Se: "St", Pal: "n", Ape: "", tas: "ns", tpace: "" } } } } } } } },
    result = getKeys(data);

console.log(result.map(a => a.join(' ')));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Last parent and last node:

```js
function getKeys(object, parent = 'noParent') {
    return object && typeof object === 'object'
        ? Object
            .entries(object)
            .reduce((r, [k, v]) => [...r, [parent, k], ...getKeys(v, k)], [])
        : [];
}

var data = { v1: { Cr: { getrt: { input: { R: { Cd: "nt", Ud: "ing", Pd: "g", Mr: "ng", Se: "ng", Pe: "ing", Psion: "g", Rt: "L", Cd2: "xsring", Cag: "xsngth", NnfigID: "xsng", CryFlag1: "xength", C2: "xength", Custo3: "xength", Cus4: "xngth", tars: "ns", taace: "h.0" }, Reqails: { Amber: "xsd:string", B: "x", KenMI: "xg", targas: "ns", targace: "h" }, Inqutails: { "Inqnt[]": { Ar: "x", B: "x", KI: "x", ts: "ns", tce: "h0" }, tas: "ns", tace: "h" }, Reqdy: { Ise: "Inq", Tnt: "x", Ald: "x", Fme: "x", Fmjke: "xtern", Mme: "xttern", Lame: "xs", Fals: { "Ado[]": { Addme: "x", Adde: "AdnalNam", taas: "", taace: "ht" }, Noents: "x", talias: "n", tapace: "h" }, Ad1: "xh", A2: "x", Ae1: "xs", St: "x", L1: "xs", L2: "xs", Cy: "x", Ste: "S", Pal: "x", Is: { "I[]": { Aine: "x", Set: "xth", L1: "x", L2: "x", C: "x", Se: "St", Pal: "n", Ape: "", tas: "ns", tpace: "" } } } } } } } },
    result = getKeys(data);

console.log(result.map(a => a.join(' ')));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Is there a way to get just the immediate parent and not the whole tree?

Comment: it is, if i know what you want (this is always a problem without wanted data). please add the result.

Comment: Made the changes in my question :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data is of the following form:

```
const data = {
  'parent': {
    'child1': 1,
    'child2': 2,
    'child3': {
      'child31': 31,
      'child32': 32
    },
    'child4': 4
  }
}
```

You have the right idea about recursing over it, but two elements needed in recursion are:

1. Have a base case to terminate on,
2. Recurse on a (hopefully reduced) value.

In this case, the base case (1.) is having no children, so we write this function, which will return `true` if an element has no children. You will probably have to change it for arrays.

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
  let numProperties = 0;
  for (let property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      ++numProperties;
    }
  }
  return numProperties === 0;
}
```

With a base case and some data, let's recurse over it. You want to apply a function to every parent (key) and its child (element), and then call it on every child (2.), so we write a mapping function for unordered trees:

```
function mapParentChildPairs(f, obj) {
  // If this element has no children, we have reached the end, so stop
  if (isEmpty(obj)) {
    return;
  } else {
    // Otherwise, get each key in the object
    for (let item in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        // Apply the function to the key and its value
        f(item, obj[item]);
        // And recurse over the item at that key, which may be more objects
        // or simply an atomic value that will end the recursion.
        mapParentChildPairs(f, obj[item]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your example used `console.log`, so let us pass that in as the function:

```
mapParentChildPairs(console.log, data);
```